# What does Nietzsche mean by a philosopher betraying something of his own ideal when he asserts what the greatest person is like?

Tags: nietzsche

In [Beyond Good and Evil aphorism/paragraph 212](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4363/4363-h/4363-h.htm) says this:

> At present, on the contrary, when throughout Europe the herding-animal
>   alone attains to honours, and dispenses honours, when "equality of
>   right" can too readily be transformed into equality in wrong—I mean to
>   say into general war against everything rare, strange, and privileged,
>   against the higher man, the higher soul, the higher duty, the higher
>   responsibility, the creative plenipotence and lordliness—at present it
>   belongs to the conception of "greatness" to be noble, to wish to be
>   apart, to be capable of being different, to stand alone, to have to
>   live by personal initiative, and the philosopher will betray something
>   of his own ideal when he asserts "He shall be the greatest who can be
>   the most solitary, the most concealed, the most divergent, the man
>   beyond good and evil, the master of his virtues, and of
>   super-abundance of will; precisely this shall be called GREATNESS: as
>   diversified as can be entire, as ample as can be full."

Why would a philospher be betraying something of his own ideal when he asserts that last sentence quoted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "betray" in the following sentence may be paraphrased as "expose to others" rather than do something harmful to his own ideal:

> ...the philosopher will betray something of his own ideal when he asserts "He shall be the greatest who can be the most solitary, the most concealed, the most divergent, the man beyond good and evil, the master of his virtues, and of super-abundance of will; precisely this shall be called GREATNESS: as diversified as can be entire, as ample as can be full."

Why should exposure to others be a problem? If Nietzsche is right that there is a

> war against everything rare, strange, and privileged, against the higher man, the higher soul, the higher duty, the higher responsibility, the creative plenipotence and lordliness

then he may be exposing to his opposition that he is not on the side of the "herding-animal" which may make him a target in this war.